# Colab not allowing use of %%writefile into google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, mount

In colab I can write the contents of a cell into file like so

%%writefile Testtext.txt
blah blah blah

This will produce a text file with 'blah blah blah'

But when I try to write it into my Google drive like so

%%writefile gdrive/My Drive/Testtext.txt
blah blah blah

I get this error

UsageError: unrecognized arguments: Drive/Testtext.txt

My drive is mounted.

Comment: The problem is the space between "My" and "Drive". You may need to use \ to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, You can change the directory to google drive

```
  %cd /content/drive/My\ Drive
```

and use  `%%writefile`

Comment: it says %%writefile invalid syntax if directory is changed before.